# unable to set textView1.setAutoLinkMask(0) - it remains clickable

Tags: android

I try to reuse a TextView. Sometimes it contains a URL and sometimes not. If I try to set the TextView back to textView.setAutoLinkMask(0) it does unfortunately nothing and the new text remains clickable.

```
TextView snippet = new TextView();
snippet.setText("someText");
if (ifSomeTextContainsURL) {
        // Recognize web URLs
        Linkify.addLinks(snippet, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
        snippet.setLinksClickable(true);
    } else {
        Linkify.addLinks(snippet, 0);
        snippet.setLinksClickable(false);
        snippet.setAutoLinkMask(0x00000000);

}
```

I tried the above code but it doesn't work for me.
Thx for help

Comment: You are not reusing any `TextView`s, because when you call *new TextView()*, this instantiates a new `TextView` Object.

Answer (score 20):

I ended up solving this issue by setting the autolinkmask *before* I set the text of the TextView:

```
textview.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
textview.setText("String with url - http://www.example.com/");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have already found the answer, but to further clear this out...

The documentation for `setAutoLinkMask(int)` method [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setAutoLinkMask%28int%29)

says that:
"Sets the autolink mask of the text. See Linkify.ALL and peers for possible values."

so only values listed in the docs for Linkify [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#ALL) are valied. '0' is not one of them so it is meaningless to send it to this method.